# Difference between an ARIN assigned netblock and an ASN?

Tags: networking

What is the difference between an ASN, which as far as I can make out is a collection of systems with a number assigned to them, and a netblock assigned to an organization by ARIN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a simple answer:

ASN is managed by IANA and give block to RIR (Regional Internet Registries) like ARIN.

For a real life example, an ISP that need a network block in North America would ask ARIN. The ISP can't have public IP if the RIR refuse. ARIN would offer a netblock and after the ISP can lease those public address.

As quoted [there](https://www.iana.org/assignments/as-numbers/as-numbers.xhtml), ASN got 5 major RIR under it;

> Autonomous System (AS) Numbers are used by various routing protocols.
>   IANA allocates  AS Numbers to Regional Internet Registries (RIRs). The
>   RIRs further allocate or assign AS  Numbers to network operators in
>   line with RIR policies. The [five RIRs] are:
>
> - [AFRINIC]
> - [APNIC]
> - [ARIN]
> - [LACNIC]
> - [RIPE_NCC]

Answer (score 0):

ASN stands for Autonomous Systems Number, [as defined by APNIC](https://www.apnic.net/get-ip/faqs/asn/) (Asia-Pacific Network Information Centre):

> An AS is a group of IP networks operated by one or more network
>   operator(s) that has a single and clearly defined external routing
>   policy.

Assigned netblocks are given to companies or organisations which pay one of the five RIRs (AFRINIC, APNIC, ARIN, LACNIC or RIPE_NCC) so the Autonomous Systems (ASes) can route them via their "clearly defined external routing policy".

For example, Netflix will route data to your netblock using the shortest AS path. See [here](https://openconnect.netflix.com/en/deployment-guide/network-configuration/).

> 2. The appliance that receives the route to the client’s netblock with
>      the shortest AS path.

The AS path is the designated name which is advertised in BGP, and the netblock is the addresses advertised in BGP. See [here](https://itservice-bg.net/mikrotik-bgp-dynamic-routing-full-table-three-peers/) for BGP explanation. As you can see in the image, one AS number can have multiple netblocks, which is the separation between AS numbers and netblocks.

[image: AS Numbers and Netblocks advertised in BGP.]